# DotNetNuke redirects when calling ImageResizer with fake extension

Tags: iis, web-config, dotnetnuke, imageresizer

I've installed the ImageResizer libraries in my DotNetNuke environment as described at http://imageresizing.net/docs/workswith/dotnetnuke

But I'm getting redirected to the root of my portal as soon as I call the resizer extension

My resize settings in the web.config look exactly the same as the example in the installation guide

```
<resizer>
    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
    <plugins>
        <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
        <add name="DiskCache" />
    </plugins>
</resizer>
```

Looks good to me, but as soon as i try to call an image through the extension, I get redirected to the root of the site.

Call to:

```
http://localhost/Portal/0/Image.jpg.ashx
```

Redirects to:

```
http://localhost/
```

I can't figure out how to fix this. Is it a DotNetNuke or a IIS setting?

Things I already tried:

- Checked the Configuration of the site and made sure the .ashx extension has the "Verify that file exists" checkbox unchecked.
- Tried using an other extension
- Tried adding a wildcard in IIS
- checked resizer.debug.ashx,

  2 Issues detected:

  ```
  (Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.
  Server(Warning):    Microsoft-IIS/6.0 does not support Integrated mode or does not have it enabled.
      You must append the .ashx extension to any image requests you wish to process.
  ```

It seems the handler is never called and the redirect takes place based on the fact that there's no physical file called Image.jpg.ashx.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a defective rewriterule in SiteUrls.config causing this problem:

```
<RewriterRule>
  <LookFor>[^?]*/(\d+)/(.*)</LookFor>
  <SendTo>~/Default.aspx?tabid=$1</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```